# HTML Special characters in DB and echo back in input

Tags: php, html, mysql, htmlspecialchars

Morning,

I have created a small form to store some information to a database.

I have magic_quotes_gpc turned off on my server.

If i enter a `"` or a `£` sign in the box is stores into the database without a worry.

When i echo it back with php it displays, but if i use the value in an input form field the `"` close the value field.

```
<input type="text" name="variable" value="<?php echo $row[variable]; ?>" />
```

I have now used htmlspecialchars around the input value and it works.

```
<input type="text" name="variable" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[variable]); ?>" />
```

But i have looked at open cart source as a reference and they do not use htmlspecialchars but store the data in a different way.

I tried using the urlencodes method they have used :

```
urlencode(html_entity_decode($_POST[variable],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

but this seems to store as a lot of numbers and + signs which did not display back correctly.

I would rather encode the update database instead of using the method i am with `htmlspecialschars`.

But not quite sure which way would be best?

Thank You

Comment: "I would rather encode the update database instead of using the method i am with htmlspecialschars." — Stop wanting that. Encoding data as HTML immediately before inserting it into HTML is the sensible approach. It preserves data in a clean format until the last minute, so if you ever need to put it somewhere that isn't HTML it will still be fine.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $string)` instead of `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
htmlentities() function in php
```

Answer (score -2):

For storing the HTML Character change the charters and then store them:

```
<?php
      $new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
      echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

To get back the correct HTML Character do the decoding as:

```
<?php
      $str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

      echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

      // note that here the quotes aren't converted
      echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

For more information refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php